# Large memory usage when calculating std dev over rolling window

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray

I have a 2D array, and I want to calculate the mean and standard deviation over a spatial window of `win_size` pixels (~50 pixels or more). I only need to extract this for a subset of pixels whose coordinates I have stored in two arrays.

My code looks like this:

```
# Set up rolling window, centred at pixel
R_spatial = R.rolling({"x": win_size, "y": win_size}, center=True)
# Calculate mean for a range of pixels
R_mean = R_spatial.mean().isel(x=x_loc_idx, y=y_loc_idx).compute()
# Calculate standard deviation
R_std = R_spatial.std().isel(x=x_loc_idx, y=y_loc_idx).compute()
```

The mean is calculated without any issues, but the standard deviation calculations starts eating more and more memory until it crashes the Python interpreter.

The problem goes away if I launch a large cluster, but I thought that xarray/dask were able to cope with calculations too big to fit in memory?

Any clues?
xarray and dask versions are 2023.05

### Memory profiling

A simple benchmarking exercise using e.g., `mprof run run_me.py`, where `run_me.py` is shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
from memory_profiler import profile


def create_data(N = 3500, n_samps = 5):
    R = xr.DataArray(np.random.randn(N, N), dims=["x", "y"]).chunk({"x":256, "y":256})
    x_loc_idx, y_loc_idx = np.random.randint(0,N, (2, n_samps))
    return R, x_loc_idx, y_loc_idx

@profile
def do_mean(R, x_loc_idx, y_loc_idx, win_size = 21):
    # Set up rolling window, centred at pixel
    R_spatial = R.rolling({"x": win_size, "y": win_size}, center=True)
    # Calculate mean for a range of pixels
    return R_spatial.mean().isel(x=x_loc_idx, y=y_loc_idx).compute()

@profile
def do_std(R, x_loc_idx, y_loc_idx, win_size = 21):
    # Set up rolling window, centred at pixel
    R_spatial = R.rolling({"x": win_size, "y": win_size}, center=True)
    # Calculate mean for a range of pixels
    return R_spatial.std().isel(x=x_loc_idx, y=y_loc_idx).compute()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    R, x_loc_idx, y_loc_idx = create_data()
    for win_size in [11, 31]:
        mu = do_mean(R, x_loc_idx, y_loc_idx, win_size=win_size)
        sigma = do_std(R, x_loc_idx, y_loc_idx, win_size=win_size)
```

Running this returns on my system:

```
$ mprof run run_me.py 
mprof: Sampling memory every 0.1s
running new process
running as a Python program...
Filename: run_me.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    11    295.4 MiB    295.4 MiB           1   @profile
    12                                         def do_mean(R, x_loc_idx, y_loc_idx, win_size = 21):
    13                                             # Set up rolling window, centred at pixel
    14    295.5 MiB      0.1 MiB           1       R_spatial = R.rolling({"x": win_size, "y": win_size}, center=True)
    15                                             # Calculate mean for a range of pixels
    16    344.0 MiB     48.5 MiB           1       return R_spatial.mean().isel(x=x_loc_idx, y=y_loc_idx).compute()


Filename: run_me.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    18    344.0 MiB    344.0 MiB           1   @profile
    19                                         def do_std(R, x_loc_idx, y_loc_idx, win_size = 21):
    20                                             # Set up rolling window, centred at pixel
    21    344.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       R_spatial = R.rolling({"x": win_size, "y": win_size}, center=True)
    22                                             # Calculate mean for a range of pixels
    23    333.3 MiB    -10.8 MiB           1       return R_spatial.std().isel(x=x_loc_idx, y=y_loc_idx).compute()


Filename: run_me.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    11    333.3 MiB    333.3 MiB           1   @profile
    12                                         def do_mean(R, x_loc_idx, y_loc_idx, win_size = 21):
    13                                             # Set up rolling window, centred at pixel
    14    333.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       R_spatial = R.rolling({"x": win_size, "y": win_size}, center=True)
    15                                             # Calculate mean for a range of pixels
    16    345.4 MiB     12.1 MiB           1       return R_spatial.mean().isel(x=x_loc_idx, y=y_loc_idx).compute()


Filename: run_me.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    18    345.4 MiB    345.4 MiB           1   @profile
    19                                         def do_std(R, x_loc_idx, y_loc_idx, win_size = 21):
    20                                             # Set up rolling window, centred at pixel
    21    345.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       R_spatial = R.rolling({"x": win_size, "y": win_size}, center=True)
    22                                             # Calculate mean for a range of pixels
    23    440.0 MiB     94.6 MiB           1       return R_spatial.std().isel(x=x_loc_idx, y=y_loc_idx).compute()
```

If I set up `win_size` to be e.g. 41, or increase the number of samples to 10, the program crashes after having eaten all the memory (this is on my laptop running Linux). Using Dask GatewaySerrvers, I can process the kind of loads I was expecting (n_samps 10000s, win_size~61).

The calculation is fairly trivial, and I could test other alternatives (numba by expanding all the neighbourhood calculations u sing loops, or using `map_blocks`, ...), but I wanted to get familiar with xarray, so was wondering about this result?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example? I'm not sure why the mean works fine and not the standard deviation. Dask should help with calculations to big to fit in memory, but it also depends on the computation and the data chunking. Rolling window is hard to handle in a distributed way.

Comment: @GuillaumeEB I have updated the question with an MWE, as well as some profiling results.

Comment: I'm not sure about the algorithm and the logic behind Rolling windows and operations. mean is an aggregation, it can be computed with very fiew memory footprint. Standard deviation is more complex though, and seem to need a lot of memory for each window.  I'm not really sure why here, but I'm probably failing to understand some of it.